"Business" or "businesses"
There are two tags on this wiki - business and businesses. Which one should we keep?

Keep business, because that's the most obvious tag. Either way, though, merge the services tag with it. 

I would keep “businesses” which is less ambiguous than “business”, with the following description:

Questions about specific bitcoin-related businesses.


Note: if this is the convention we adopt, on some questions the tag should be removed, on some others it should be added.

I think we should keep businesses, as plural forms appear to be more appropriate for tags.
